# How do I get the DeviceName ("\\.\DISPLAY1") that corresponds to a PNPDeviceID ("SWD\MyEnumerator\MyInstance")?

Tags: windows, user32, setupapi

To manage display adapters and display properties, my code uses APIs from two different Windows DLLs:

## CfgMgr32.dll

I use functions in CfgMgr32 (successor to SetupApi) to:

- enumerate adapters (get ids & properties)
- determine whether a specific adapter exists
- determine whether an adapter is enabled/disabled
- enabled/disabled an adapter
- register a callback to receive PnP device events

APIs in CfgMgr32 (and SetupApi) use an adapter id (called *DeviceInstanceId* or *PNPDeviceID*) of the form: `"SWD\MyEnumerator\MyInstance"`

## User32.dll

I use functions in User32 to:

- enumerate adapters (get ids & properties)
- query an adapter's supported resolutions
- query an adapter's current display mode
- change an adapter's current orientation
- change an adapter's current resolution

APIs in User32 uses use a *completely different* adapter id (called *DeviceName*) of the form: `"\\.\DISPLAY23"`

## The (Astonishing) Problem:

There appears to be *no documented way* of mapping between these two forms of unique identifiers. I can enable an adapter, but when I want to change its orientation or resolution, I have no way of knowing which of the identifiers returned by `EnumDisplayDevices(...)` refers to the same adapter I just enabled.

The APIs I need are split across two libraries; neither library provides a complete set of display adapter management functions.

Both libraries have functions that let you get information about a particular adapter, and there is some minor overlap, but critically: *nothing that's unique to a single adapter*. Maybe there's some way to unambiguously relate properties from one side to the other, but I've dumped out everything that's available (including SystemInformation, Screen.AllScreens, Wmi queries like Win32_VideoController, DISPLAY_DEVICE...) and in all that information I can't find anything *mappable*.

Has anyone solved this, or know of some open source project that might be worth looking over?

Comment: It looks like EnumDisplayDevices returns the User32 name in `DeviceName` and the PNP name in `DeviceID`. Perhaps that is your Rosetta Stone.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I get DeviceID="<unique-to-the-model-section hardware identifier>", which either comes from the INF or `SW_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO.pszHardwareIds` or `.pszCompatibleIds`. This info isn't unique to the instance.

Comment: Oh well. Sorry. I tried.